# Check if relation exists and return true or false

Tags: sql, join, relational-database

I have 3 tables, `Category` `Step` and `CategoryStep`, where `CategoryStep` relates the two other tables together.  I want to return all categories with a true/false column whether or not the relation exists in `CategoryStep` based on a StepID.

The schema for the tables is simple,

```
Category:
CategoryID      | CategoryName

Step:
StepID          | StepName

CategoryStep:
CategoryStepID  | CategoryID    | StepID
```

When trying to get results based on StepID, I only get the relations that exist, and not ones that don't.

```
SELECT [CategoryID], [Category], CAST(CASE WHEN [CategoryStep].[CategoryStep] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS related
FROM Category
LEFT JOIN CategoryStep ON Category.CategoryID = CategoryStep.CategoryID
INNER JOIN Step ON CategoryStep.StepID = Step.StepID
WHERE Step.StepID = 2
```

Step Table:

```
|StepID | StepName
|-------|---------
| 1     | StepOne
| 2     | StepTwo
| 3     | StepThree
```

Category Table:

```
| CategoryID | CategoryName
|------------|-------------
| 1          | Holidays
| 2          | States
| 3          | Cities
| 4          | Animals
| 5          | Food
```

CategoryStep Table

```
| CategoryStepID | CategoryID | StepID
|----------------|------------|-------
| 1              | 1          | 1
| 2              | 1          | 2     <--
| 3              | 2          | 1
| 4              | 2          | 3
| 5              | 3          | 2     <--
| 6              | 4          | 1
| 7              | 4          | 2     <--
| 8              | 4          | 3
| 9              | 5          | 1
| 10             | 5          | 3
```

So, if I was looking for StepID = 2 the result table I am looking for is:

```
| CategoryID | Category | Related
|------------|----------|--------
| 1          | Holidays | 1
| 2          | States   | 0
| 3          | Cities   | 1
| 4          | Animals  | 1
| 5          | Food     | 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing the `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN`.

**Update:**

The fatal flaw with your original attempt was the `WHERE` clause.  You were performing the correct `LEFT JOIN`, but the `WHERE` clause was filtering off category records which did not match.  In the query below, I moved the check for step ID into the join condition, where it belongs.

```
SELECT [CategoryID], [Category],
    CAST(CASE WHEN [CategoryStep].[CategoryStep] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS related
FROM Category
LEFT JOIN CategoryStep
    ON Category.CategoryID = CategoryStep.CategoryID AND
       CategoryStep.StepCodeID = 2
LEFT JOIN Step
    ON CategoryStep.StepID = Step.StepID
```

Comment: Still not seeing the non-related categories, only the categories that have a relation.  I thought this was the way to go about it, but there is something I'm missing.

Comment: Show us some sample data please.